# AnyLogic: compensating for double overflow in GISRegion.area()

Tags: java, double, geospatial, geofencing, anylogic

I'm trying to sort a collection of AnyLogic `GISRegions` by their geographical area. Said area is calculated using `GISRegion.area(units)`, which is straightforward enough. The areas I'm using, however, are city-scale and the method returns a `double`. This appears to cause overflow problems:

[image]

I don't think I'm doing anything wrong with my code, so presumably this is an AnyLogic problem. For brevity, I've included a line that prints each region's area rather than the sorting steps:

```
// For each region of the Australian Capital Territory, print its area in km^2:
areas.forEach(next -> traceln(""+next.name+": " + next.gisRegion.area(SQ_KILOMETER)));
```

Has anyone encountered this issue? How did you get around it?

For non-AnyLogic users, I have all the lat-long points in each geoshape. How might I calculate the area using those points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Not really a full answer, but the ideas are too long for a comment.*]

I assume you've raised an AnyLogic support request since it seems 100% a bug. Since this is just a basic 'calculate area' function, I can't see any way round it other than, as you suggest, calculating it in an alternative manner from the vertex lat/longs that you have, and can get via `getPoints()` on the `GISRegion`.

Since this is just an N-sided polygon, surely there must be standard Java libraries that could calculate that, though that's not allowing for the GIS projection (not sure what level of error that might introduce); you'd expect open GIS libraries to cope with the latter. Since a `GISRegion` has a `createOMGraphicObject()` method to create an OpenMap standard(?) format graphic, that could be useful if that's a standard format other libraries can work with.

There's code on glennon's answer to [this GIS StackOverflow question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/711) that claims to perform the calculation (or you make be able to hook in to PostGIS as in fmark's answer).